# how to find pow() methods using Swift Standard Library Reference

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and is trying to understand how to use Swift Standard Library Reference. I have past experience in Java and if I want to find a class or a class's method, I simply type e.g. **String.charAt() Java SE8** in Google and the first result shown is the latest offical Oracle documentation on String class. However, if I want to find a class or method in Swift, when I type in e.g. **pow() Swift Standard Library Reference**, google only shows the main page to Swift Standard Library Reference, not the page of the class that actually contain the method. Could someone please tell me how to actually search the Swift Library? It would help me a great deal! Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Xcode just go to Help > Documentation and API Reference